# Using Refine function and take real part of a symbolic expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, assumptions

I am trying to take the real part of the a complex expression using `Refine` function. 
However, the result doesn't come out as expected. The final result still contains `Im` function.

Does anyone have some idea what is going on here?

```
expr = x + (I*(y + z))/(m + I*n); 
evar = Variables[expr]; 
Refine[Re[expr], Element[evar, Reals]]
```

Output:

```
x - (y + z)*Im[1/(m + I*n)]
```

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand[Re[x + (I (y + z))/(m + I n)]]`.

Comment: It works but I have read that using Refine is better so I would like to use it.